# Is my apache spark usage right?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

Follow up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933456/data-load-time-when-using-spark-with-oracle) instead of oracle I am using hdfs. I am doing following computation on 8G of plain csv. Each time I fetch result it takes 7 min. I have 5 Servers with 20G of memory each. How to decrease execution  time?

```
#loading data from hdfs
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("dateFormat","dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS").option("inferSchema", "true").load("hdfs://10.10.10.11:8020/sparkfiles/alarmfiles/export.csv")
```

## change datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,udf
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType
import re
def datefun(firstoccurrence):
    return datetime.strptime(re.sub(r'\d{3}( .M)$', r'\1', firstoccurrence),'%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p')
dt_conv =  udf (datefun, TimestampType())
```

---

```
groupbyalerts1 = df.groupBy('ALERTGROUP').count().sort('count', ascending=False)

groupbyalerts2 = groupbyalerts1.filter(groupbyalerts1['ALERTGROUP'] != '')

groupbyalerts = groupbyalerts2.filter(groupbyalerts2['ALERTGROUP'] != '0')

groupbyalerts.show(30,False)
```

---

Log output during n/w activity:

```
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 4.0 in stage 18.0 (TID 980) in 4080 ms on analytics1.com (4/54)
16/08/19 09:01:37 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 7.0 in stage 18.0 (TID 983, analytics2.com, partition 7
16/08/19 16:23:24 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_86_piece0 in memory on analytics2.com:57096 (size: 25.9 KB, free: 8.4 GB)
```

Computation Logs:

```
16/08/19 16:18:28 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 22.0 in stage 57.0 (TID 2563, analytics4.com, partition 22,NODE_LOCAL, 2324 bytes)
16/08/19 16:18:28 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 18.0 in stage 57.0 (TID 2559) in 28654 ms on analytics4.com (19/54)
16/08/19 16:18:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 23.0 in stage 57.0 (TID 2564, nanalytics3.com, partition 23,NODE_LOCAL, 2324 bytes)
16/08/19 16:18:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 20.0 in stage 57.0 (TID 2560) in 31702 ms on analytics3.com (20/54)
```

Comment: Excluding `inferSchema` there is nothing obviously wrong here.

Comment: @zero323 I removed it and still see the delay with each task taking  28s as in log which is 2 out of 54th task? I am confused that my way is not correct. *21:45:36 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 8.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 9) in 28848 ms on analytics.com 2/54*

Comment: So the next problem here is Python UDF.

Comment: @zero323 any suggestions? I want the data in date format.

Comment: There is nothing here that cannot be handled by builtin Spark SQL functions.

Comment: @zero323 removing inferschema and udf did the trick. Is this possible to add it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try to to avoid schema inference. With default settings it requires additional data scan and it is way more expensive than explicit casting. In other words provide schema for reader:

```
schema  = StructType([...])
df = sqlContext.read.schema(schema).format(...)
```

The same way it is better to avoid Python UDFs. While UDF performance increased in 2.0+ it is still suboptimal. In this scenario you can easily replace it with a combination of:

- `pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace`
- `pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp` with simple date format for parsing to `Long`
- and finally simple type casting to date